# Javascript - Array length doesn't work if characters "{","}" or ":" are present

Tags: javascript, arrays

Everyone!
I have an array of items, and I want to return a number of how many values match a specific State in the US.
For example, this is working code:
https://jsfiddle.net/fkj3bq5g/

JS:

```
const arr = ["Texas","Austin","TX","Texas","San Antonio","TX","California","Los Angeles","CA"];
const results = arr.filter(elem => elem === "Texas").length;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = results;
```

html:

```
<span>Texas Cities:</span><span id="demo"></span>
```

I''m trying to match "Texas" and it should return "2",which it does.
However, I encounter a problem as soon as I'm trying to put an array from a JSON file, which has characters like ``` {, ``} ``` and `:` - I'm not getting any results. I'm not sure why since I'm pretty much a noob anyway.

Here's an example how the array in the `.json` file looks like:

```
var state_city = [
{"state":"Texas","city":"Houston","code":"TX"},
{"state":"Texas","city":"Dallas","code":"TX"},
{"state":"Texas","city":"Austin","code":"TX"},
{"state":"California","city":"Los Angeles","code":"CA"},
{"state":"California","city":"Sacramento","code":"CA"},
{"state":"California","city":"Anaheim","code":"CA"},
]
```

How do i make this work?

Comment: `elem` is an **Object** now, so `elem.state` has the word "texas"

Comment: by the way - that's not JSON, that's just an object you are declaring ... if you put that code exactly like that in a `.json file and try to load it, it won't work

Comment: You array does not have `{`  and `:` characters in it. You have created an array of object values. You'll have to filter by the value of the object "state" properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```js
const results = arr.filter(elem => elem === "Texas").length
```

Now each `elem` evaluates to an object in `state_city`, so you want to modify your code a little:

```js
const results = arr.filter(elem => elem.state === "Texas").length
```

Comment: That's fantastic, @Igor, worked like a charm! - fiddle = https://jsfiddle.net/fkj3bq5g/

Comment: @WilliamNassian Glad to help! :) Please consider [marking the answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) in case it resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Once you load your `json` content into a variable, it will become an array of objects, not strings, so a simple `===` comparison will not work. You can compare it with the correct property, which in your case, is `state`:

```js
var state_city = [
  {"state":"Texas","city":"Houston","code":"TX"},
  {"state":"Texas","city":"Dallas","code":"TX"},
  {"state":"Texas","city":"Austin","code":"TX"},
  {"state":"California","city":"Los Angeles","code":"CA"},
  {"state":"California","city":"Sacramento","code":"CA"},
  {"state":"California","city":"Anaheim","code":"CA"},
]

const count = state_city.filter(item => item.state === 'Texas').length;
console.log(count);
```

If you still want to do string comparison, you can do it by `stringify`ing your json result. It will find any string occurrence in each object:

```js
var state_city = [
  {"state":"Texas","city":"Houston","code":"TX"},
  {"state":"Texas","city":"Dallas","code":"TX"},
  {"state":"Texas","city":"Austin","code":"TX"},
  {"state":"California","city":"Los Angeles","code":"CA"},
  {"state":"California","city":"Sacramento","code":"CA"},
  {"state":"California","city":"Anaheim","code":"CA"},
]

const count = state_city.filter(item => JSON.stringify(item).includes('Texas')).length;
console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your sample code you iterates a simple array of strings. So, you've defined that array as follows.

```
const arr = ["Texas","Austin","TX","Texas","San 
Antonio","TX","California","Los Angeles","CA"];
```

So, you can iterate all the elements in that array and filter out how many times your condition is true. As you did.

```
const results = arr.filter(elem => elem === "Texas").length;
```

But in your .json file, you have defined a different format of an array compared to previous one. It is an array of 
    objects.

```
var state_city = [
{"state":"Texas","city":"Houston","code":"TX"},
{"state":"Texas","city":"Dallas","code":"TX"},
{"state":"Texas","city":"Austin","code":"TX"},
{"state":"California","city":"Los Angeles","code":"CA"},
{"state":"California","city":"Sacramento","code":"CA"},
{"state":"California","city":"Anaheim","code":"CA"},
]
```

In here `var state_city` is the array and {} are objects 
   inside that array.

So, you can't directly access those attributes which you 
   declared in those objects by using the above mentioned 
   way.

So, you have to try this way.

```
const results = state_city.filter(elem => elem.state === 
"Texas").length;
```